# Java JDBC SQLite display results from table B that match primary key from table A

Tags: java, sqlite, search, relational-database, primary-key

I am new to JDBC and SQLite. I have 2 tables, table A and table B.

I want to search table B and display all the results in that table where the foreign key of table B matches the primary key of table A. So essentially I want to do the following:

Search Table B where foreign key like String (Primary key) Table A.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Is your problem related to crafting together the correct sql query, or is your problem with the jdbc syntax, that is, how to execute queries and fetching results using jdbc in java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select * 
from tableB b
inner join tableA a on a.primaryA = b.primaryB
```

please look up to KEY(inner join) for detail infos.